# JSF: How to let #{...} expansion not be escaped?

Tags: jsf, escaping, facelets, el

I have a custom EL function (defined in `myfunctions.taglib.xml`) which returns a chunk of HTML, I want to copy it verbatim to the output,

```
<f:verbatim>
    #{mylib:generateHtml()}
</f:verbatim>
```

however, the expansion of #{...} is always escaped. How to make it not be escaped?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe there is an option for escape characters with verbatim.

```
<f:verbatim escape="#{boolean}" />
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `<h:outputText escape="false" />`. The `<f:verbatim>` serves an entirely different purpose specifically for JSP views and is dangerous on Facelets and is **deprecated** in JSF 2.0.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.html}" escape="false" />
```

Comment: How can I manage to output #{bean.myProperty} without having JSF to interpret this String? I do not want to create a bean returning this String. Is there a output component to do this?